# __doPostBack is not working in .net 4.0

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have website in asp.net 4.0, where i used,

```
litAlert.Text = "<script language=javascript>alert('Some Error(s) occured while processing your request. Click Ok to view the Error Details.');__doPostBack('btnTemp','')</script>";
```

But when i am trying to debug, it will not call btnTemp onclick event.

Please give me solution regarding this issue.

Comment: Does `__doPostBack` exist on in the final rendered document?

Comment: No,It is not working in my document

Comment: try to look for javascript exception with firebug or chrome dev tools

Answer (score 1):

You could at this to Page_PreRender

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(litAlert, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: +1: I could not find any explicit reference to this , but if on your page there are no controls that cause a postback, e.g. an `asp:Button`, then `__doPostBack` will not be defined by default, and calling `GetPostBackEventReference` should be the solution.